# Encrypt and Decrypt data using Blowfish with Coldfusion and .NET/BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, encryption, coldfusion, bouncycastle, blowfish

I am trying to mimic coldfusion Blowfish/Hex encryption using BouncyCastle for ASP.NET MVC. I was able to successfully decrypt a string encrypted in CF using the steps laid out in this link: [Encrypt and Decrypt data using Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772039/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-using-blowfish-cbc-pkcs5padding)

Other than adding a \0 to the end of the 7 character string, it works great.

I am not trying to utilize Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding, just Blowfish/Hex. I am unable to get the reverse (encryption) working. Below is the code I have so far

I have tried using manual padding of =, as well as ignoring. However, even when using the additional character, it still doesn't sync.

Decryption (does work):

```
string keyString = "TEST";
BlowfishEngine engine = new BlowfishEngine();
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(engine);
cipher.Init(false, new KeyParameter(Convert.FromBase64String(keyString)));
byte[] out1 = Hex.Decode(hexstring);
byte[] out2 = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(out1.Length)];
int len2 = cipher.ProcessBytes(out1, 0, out1.Length, out2, 0);
cipher.DoFinal(out2, len2);
string myval = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(out2);
```

Encryption (doesn't work):

```
string keyString = "TEST";
string stringToEncrypt = "0123456";
stringToEncrypt = stringToEncrypt + "=";
BlowfishEngine engine2 = new BlowfishEngine();
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher2 = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(engine2);
cipher2.Init(true, new KeyParameter(Convert.FromBase64String(keyString)));
byte[] inB = Hex.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(stringToEncrypt));
byte[] outB = new byte[cipher2.GetOutputSize(inB.Length)];
int len1 = cipher2.ProcessBytes(inB, 0, inB.Length, outB, 0);
cipher2.DoFinal(outB, len1);
var myval2 = BitConverter.ToString(outB).Replace("-", "");
```

"Doesn't work" meaning - it returns an encrypted string that in no way mirrors the string encrypted by CF. On top of that, the returned string, when decrypted using the above method, does not match with what was originally entered (using the .NET/BouncyCastle encryption)

Comment: Could you elaborate on "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Sure. It returns an encrypted string that in no way mirrors the string encrypted by CF. On top of that, the returned string, when decrypted using the above method, does not match with what was originally entered (using the .NET/BouncyCastle encryption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# code is decoding the input as base64, when it is actually just plain text.  So you are encrypting the wrong value. That is why the result doesn't match the encrypted string from CF.  Since CF always uses UTF8, use this:

```
byte[] inB = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
```

Instead of:

```
byte[] inB = Hex.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(stringToEncrypt));
```

*Additional Security Tips:*

1. I'm no expert in encryption, but [from what I've read](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-i-use-ecb-or-cbc-encryption-mode-for-my-block-cipher), **you should use CBC mode**, with a different IV every time, for better security. (The current code uses ECB, which is less secure).
2. For anyone reading this thread in the future, obviously the key value "TEST" is just for illustration. **Don't use arbitrary values as keys**, because it weakens security. Always use strong keys generated by a standard crypto library. For example, in CF use the [GenerateSecretKey](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/generatesecretkey.html) function.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! And yes, the "TEST" is just for illustration.

Comment: @MeanDean73 - Yeah, figured *you* knew that :-) but many people just copy and paste examples on the web and may not realize using arbitrary strings for an encryption key is ... well... bad -;)